# How to use two tableview in one view?

Tags: macos, uitableview

I have two table view in one view container. I insert each of them to the container.
[image]

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildTableView") as! ChildTableViewController
        childTV.updateTable(id: indexPath.row)
}
```

I need to update second tableview when first tableview cell clicked.
How i can do this?

Comment: Just do it. What's the hard part?

Comment: i cant update second table view from first

Comment: What do you mean, you "can't"? Why not? What happens when you try it? Show your code. Explain what happens when you run it, and how that differs from what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I see the problem. The way you've done this is with two UITableViewControllers and their table views. So now you have a problem communicating between the two table view controllers. But consider this: if you've truly created child view controllers, the table view controllers are children of the same parent. So the first table view controller can get its parent view controller, then get the parent's child view controllers, then get the *second* child view controller, and that must be the second table view controller.

In other words, if your view controller hierarchy is:

```
ParentViewController
    TableViewController1
    TableViewController2
```

... then TableViewController1 can say:

```
let tvc2 = self.parent!.childViewControllers[1] as! TableViewController2
```

... and now you have established a line of communication between them. So now table view controller 1 can talk to table view controller 2 and tell it to update its table. You will need to have a method in table view controller 2 that table view controller 1 can call, in order to hand it any needed data and tell it what to do.

Answer (score 0):

in Second TableView:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChildTableViewController.updateTable(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateChild"), object: nil)
}

func updateTable(sender:NSNotification){
     tableView.reloadData()
}
```

in First TableView:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
     selectedItem["id"]=indexPath.row
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateChild"),object:selectedItem)
}
```